# Django - Filter related objects

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Let's say I have a list of locations where each location has a list of some objects. I want to make sure that I get these locations, but with a filtered list of objects.

Here's the structure of models.py:

```
class Location(models.Models):
    # fields


class LocationObject(models.Models):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="objects_list")
    # other fields that are used in filtering
```

Here's how I do filtering:

```
locations = Location.objects.all()

if request_square_from:
    locations = locations.filter(objects_list__size__gte=request_square_from)

if request_square_to:
    locations = locations.filter(objects_list__size__lte=request_square_to)

# Other filters ...
```

The problem is that, by using this method of filtering, I get in each location a list of objects in which there is *at least* one object that satisfies the condition in `locations.filter()`. This is not what I actually need. I need to exclude every object (I mean `LocationObject`) that doesn't satisfy the condition in the `filter()` method.

Is there any idea to do that?

**Update**. A bit of clarification

Here's how this list looks:

```
Location #1
   - Object 1 (size=40)
   - Object 2 (size=45)
   - Object 3 (size=30)

Location #2
   - Object 4 (size=20)
   - Object 5 (size=25)
```

I want to filter each object of location by, let's say, size property. Assume this condition: `Location.objects.filter(objects_list__size__gte=40)`. This will match locations that contain even just a single list entry that has this property. This is **not** what I need. Expected result should be:

```
Location #1:
   - Object 1 (size=40)
   - Object 2 (size=45)
```

Comment: Looks like you need just filter by `LocationObject`, later grouped by `Location`. Aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really want those locations that have at least one object that fulfills both conditions, you could do:

```
locations = locations.filter(objects_list__size__gte=request_square_from, 
                             objects_list__size__lte=request_square_to)
```

But since you are not sure to have both parameters, you cannot do that. You can, however, achieve it using `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# ...    
locations = Location.objects.all()
q = Q()    
if request_square_from:
    q &= Q(objects_list__size__gte=request_square_from)    
if request_square_to:
    q &= Q(objects_list__size__lte=request_square_to)    
if q:
    locations = locations.filter(q)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this is not what I need. This way of filtering does filter locations, but not their objects...

Comment: Then you would have to provide how/where you were going to access those.  Do you want all locations, and then later only their objects that fulfill the conditions? An example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, what you want is `exclude()`.

`filter()` is used to filter out all objects that are required. So you would use:

`locations = locations.filter(objects_list__size__gte=request_square_from)`

This will give you all the objects that satisfy this condition.

But if you want to exclude the matching query. You need to use `exclude()`

`locations = locations.exclude(objects_list__size__gte=request_square_from)`

This will give you the objects that do not satisfy the condition and returns the rest of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

According to your update, you want a list of **location objects**, not locations, so, instead of filtering your locations, filter the location objects!

```
objects = LocationObject.objects.all()
if request_square_from:
    objects = objects.filter(size__gte=request_square_from)

if request_square_to:
    objects = objects.filter(size__lte=request_square_to)
```

You are **not** restricted to filter foreign keys, you can filter over any Model instance.

If after this, you want the location of any object, you just...

```
objects[0].location
```